# Printing hash value from a MD5 SOAP::Lite service

Tags: perl, md5, soaplite

I am trying to print the result of a text input that is run through a SOAP::Lite MD5 service that I have created. This is just the preliminary code that I am testing so I can integrated it into a larger application. I am required to create my own "service" that is stored in a .cgi file that takes a text input and returns the hash value of this. Here is the code for the service I created.
http://codepad.org/dsEJpJy5

So when I use that service that I created it will show the xml data in putty which shows that it is working and creating the hash value, but I can not figure out how to assign/print that value. It has to be pretty simple, but nothing I have tried will work.

Here is the code for my perl file that I am testing this out in.
http://codepad.org/qjRpEyck

Comment: Please move the code from paste services into Stack Overflow. This site is outliving them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I found some better examples and was able to determine what I needed to focus on in the MD5 subroutine response. Now I will integrate this into my larger login form. Here is the working code [codepad.org/7gx74rwb](http://codepad.org/7gx74rwb)